# Not sure if I should use "as" or "like" in this sentence

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction

You see me just **like** an object

You see me just **as** an object

Which one would be correct ? Also I'm afraid the sentence construction isn't ok. I have to say that some person sees (or perceives, or considers) someone else as / like an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use "as" before a noun for identification, and "like" for similarity or comparison. Thus, in "He worked **as** a slave", he was a slave, while in "He worked **like** a slave", he worked as hard as a slave but was not one. In "He spoke **as** a leader", he was a leader and spoke in that capacity, while in "He spoke **like** a leader", he spoke as if he was one, that is, he spoke in the way leaders do.

With verbs like *see, consider, view, regard*, we use "as" because the person or thing is **identified** with the way they are seen or considered. If somebody sees or considers you **as** a friend, from their perspective you **are** their friend.

In the sentence:

- You see me just **as** an object.

"I" **is** an object from the point of view of "you".

In my experience as a teacher, there is only one verb where both prepositions are accepted without a significant change of meaning, and that is "treat":

- You treat me **as / like** a child (I'm not a child, but you treat me as if I were one).

Comment: A side note regarding the construction, "You see me just as an object" is technically grammatically correct, but I think most people would probably use "only" instead of "just" in this case.  Also, one can say either "only as" or "as only", which are both OK but have slightly different feelings.  "as only an object" emphasizes the "only" a bit more so it's more like "I'm an object and you won't accept me being anything more". However, "only as an object" is a little more neutral, and has more of the sense of "I'm more than an object but you just don't care whether I am or not".

Comment: Thank you both, this was really clear and helpful !